# Spring 3 webservice template for different webservice calls?

Tags: marshalling, spring-3, webservicetemplate

I am new to using `WebserviceTemplate` to make client calls.

I can use `marshalSendAndReceive(request)` for a single exposed WS. Within my client I need to call other WS too. In my `SpringConfig.xml`, 
the `jaxbMarshaller` is defined with a `p:contextPath="com.acme.domain1.service1"`. It is my understanding that the `contextpath` is used to marshall the request.

So, if I need to make a call to `service2` whose generated classes are under `com.foo.service2`, how do I do that in the same code? I was autowiring `WebserviceTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the list like

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                 <property name="contextPaths">
                        <list>
                                <value>com.acme.domain1.service1</value>
                                <value>com.foo.service2</value>
                        </list>
                </property>
</bean>
```